# Create local variable in Lua

Tags: lua

If I have a variable name("x" for example) stored in another variable (varname in this example) I can create a global variable via

```
_G[varname]=42
```

This is a complicated way to say

```
x=42
```

Now I want to do the same thing for local variables. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use a string to modify local variables, your best option is using a local table.

```
local localVars = {}

function setValue(varname, value)
  localVars[varname] = value
end

function getValue(varname)
  return localVars[varname]
end
```

You are not really creating and destroying local variables this way, but you get pretty close.

Comment: If you want local variables _per function_, then you should give each function its own `local localVars = {}`; with the way it is now, local variables are shared across all functions, and they persist between function calls. Also, as it is now, if you call a function which uses `localVars['a']` and that function then calls a function which uses `localVars['a']`, the second function will clobber the first's value.

Answer (score 11):

No, because local variables are not stored in a table, or in any structure which associates their name to them. When the lua code is compiled into bytecode, local variable names turn into numeric offsets on the lua stack.